# Launch new window on iOS app using SwiftUI Lifecycle

Tags: ios, swiftui, window

The following code on `WindowScene` does indeed open a new window on macOS when a button is pressed in `ContentView` that opens an URL:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    
        WindowGroup("Viewer") {
            Text("Viewer").padding()
        }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["*"])
    }
}
```

However, when the same is applied to iOS, the app does not do anything when the `openURL` action is called.

The result from my research is that I can use the traditional `requestSceneSessionActivation` to open window manually. However, this will defeat the purpose of using the SwiftUI app lifecycle.

Any suggestions on a working method, without reverting back to the UIKit lifecycle?

Comment: Do you mean iPad? iPhone can't open windows

Comment: Do you have your URL scheme defined in your iOS target?

Comment: @malhal Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @Adam This is configured properly. The URL scheme does open the app when it is trigged in Safari (but does not open the new window).

Comment: @TomShen Maybe iOS doesn’t like the wildcard? What happens if you replace the “*” with “test” and then openUrl with “your-url-scheme://test”?

Comment: @Adam Tried this. Still does not open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a very long research session, I finally found the property that does this in [this blog post](https://www.michaelfcollins3.me/posts/2021/01/creating-multiple-scenes-in-a-swiftui-app/).

Turns out that `requestSceneSessionActivation` is necessary, but there's no need to use a `SceneDelegate`.

When creating the new session, set the `targetContentIdentifier` on the `NSUserActivity` object.

```
let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "newWindow")
activity.userInfo = ["some key":"some value"]
activity.targetContentIdentifier = "newWindow" // IMPORTANT
UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(nil, userActivity: activity, options: nil)
```

Finally, make sure the new `WindowGroup` can handle the event with the identifier:

```
WindowGroup(id: "newWindow") {
    Text("New Window!").padding()
}
.handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["newWindow"])
```

This solution retains the SwiftUI Lifecycle, and also works on Catalyst.

---

**Update for iPadOS 16/macOS Ventura:**

You can now use the new `openWindow` environment property:

```
@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
...
openWindow(id: "newWindow")
```

Make sure the `id` passed to `openWindow` is the same as the `id` set in the `WindowGroup` or `Window` initializer.